# Delete an item without using index React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to delete the item which is right clicked. I am using `onContextMenu` and `event.preventDefault` to avoid showing the context menu. However, I don't know how to delete an item without the index. The requirement of this is not using index to do deletion.
**The class App:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activities: activities,
            filteredActivities: activities,
            isShow: false,
        };
        this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClickChange = this.handleClickChange.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    }

    deleteItem(item) {
        item.preventDefault();
        const activities = this.state.activities.slice();
        var response = confirm("Sure delete?");
        if (response == true) {
            // how to delete please?
            this.setState({
                activities: activities
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const filteredActivities = this.props.filteredActivities;
        const isShow = this.state.isShow;
        return(
            <div className="notificationsFrame">
                <div className="panel">
                    <Header name={this.props.name} onClickSearch={this.handleClickChange} onClickAdd={this.addItem} />
                    { isShow ? <SearchBar inputChanged={this.handleSearchChange} /> : null }
                    <Content activities={this.state.filteredActivities} onRightClick={this.deleteItem}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**The structure of data:**

```
const activities = [
    {img_url: "assets/dog.jpg", time: "A hour ago", content: "Have lunch.", comment_count: "2" },
    {img_url: "assets/dog.jpg", time: "5 hour ago", content: "Have breakfast.", comment_count: "0" },
    {img_url: "assets/dog.jpg", time: "6 hour ago", content: "Get up.", comment_count: "1" }
];
```

**The class content:**

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <div className="line"></div>
                {this.props.activities.map(activity =>
                    <ActivityItem img_url={activity.img_url} time={activity.time}
                        content={activity.content} comment_count={activity.comment_count} onContextMenu={this.props.onRightClick}/>
                )}  

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**The class item to show:**

```
class ActivityItem extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="item" {...this.props}>
                <div className="avatar">
                    <img src={this.props.img_url} />
                </div>

                <span className="time">
                    {this.props.time}
                </span>
                <p>
                    {this.props.content}
                </p>
                <div className="commentCount">
                    {this.props.comment_count}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The way your activities are currently structured (as an unsorted list) I don't see any other way than iterating through activities until you find item. That said, I would strongly consider adding unique ids to your activities, in your current setup you could easily have two of the same item, and you would have no idea which to delete. Also if you added unique ids, you could have a map from id to item, to make lookup easier.

Comment: Have you tried filter(), that is filtering the array. Checking for elements that met a particular condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deleteItem` need to modify a lot. The `const activities = this.state.activities.slice();` is wrong and need to modify. I also need to find the item index. Then I just splice the item out.

```
deleteItem = item => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let activities = this.state.activities;
        var response = confirm("Sure delete?");
        if (response == true) {
            for(var i = 0; i < activities.length; i++){
                if(activities[i] == item){
                    activities.splice(i,1);
                };
            };
            this.setState({
                activities: activities
            });
        };
    }
```

**The class content:**

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <div className="line"></div>
                {this.props.activities.map(activity =>
                    <ActivityItem img_url={activity.img_url} time={activity.time}
                        content={activity.content} comment_count={activity.comment_count}
                        onContextMenu={() => this.props.onRightClick(activity)} />
                )}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
deleteItem = (item) => {
    const activities = this.state.activities.slice(item, 1);
    var response = confirm("Sure delete?");
    if (response == true) {
        // how to delete please?
        this.setState({
            activities: activities
        });
    }
}
```

**The class content:**

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <div className="line"></div>
                {this.props.activities.map(activity =>
                    <ActivityItem img_url={activity.img_url} time={activity.time}
                        content={activity.content} comment_count={activity.comment_count}
                        onContextMenu={() => this.props.onRightClick(activity)} />
                )}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are nearly correct. The class component is correct but ```deleteItem``` need to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your `activities` array.

```
 deleteItem(item) {
            item.preventDefault();
            const activities = this.state.activities;
            var response = confirm("Sure delete?");
            if (response == true) {


           activities.filter((i) => {
           if (i === item) {
           items.splice(items.indexOf(i), 1);
          }
             });


                this.setState({
                    activities: activities
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: @TinFanChung, I've fixed it and I tested it , It works now.